# How can I set multiple values to null in one raster and replace all other values with another raster?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, landsat-8, cloud-cover, con, setnull

I am working with Landsat8 cloud data (BQA.tiff). I would like to set all medium and high confidence cloud/cloud shadow values (values listed below) to null and replace all other values in this image to surface temperature from another raster.

Here is one example of what I have tried--though I have tried a lot:

SetNull("q530_prj_Clip.tif" in [2800 | 2804 | 2808 | 2812 | 6896 | 6900 | 6904 | 6908 | 2976 | 2980 | 2984 | 2988 | 3008 | 3012 | 3016 | 3020 | 7072 | 7076 | 7080 | 7084 | 7104 | 7108 | 7112 | 7116 | 2752 | 2756 | 2760 | 2764 | 3008 | 3012 | 3016 | 3020 | 3776 | 3780 | 3784 | 3788 | 6848 | 6852 | 6856 | 6860 | 7104 | 7108 | 7112 | 7116 | 7872 | 7876 | 7880 | 7884],"May 30, 2013")

Answer (score 1):

There is probably a more elegant way, but you can do this using `Con`, `SetNull`, and `InList`, which functions like the `in` conditional operator you were trying.

`Con(IsNull(InList("q530_prj_Clip.tif", [2800,2804,2808,2812,6896,6900,6904,6908,2976,2980,2984,2988,3008,3012,3016,3020,7072,7076,7080,7084,7104,7108,7112,7116,2752,2756,2760,2764,3008,3012,3016,3020,3776,3780,3784,3788,6848,6852,6856,6860,7104,7108,7112,7116,7872,7876,7880,7884])), "May 30, 2013")`

`InList` returns all cells within a raster that match the values in the provided array and sets all other cells to NoData. This method may have problems if your conditional raster (`"q530_prj_Clip.tif"`) has NoData values already, so be aware of that.